# Angular Formbuilder must contain Certain Character in Validator

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I need to ensure an Angular formbuilder,  CityStateZip contains a comma,  1 or more commas is fine. What is the regex validator pattern in Angular Formbuilder to conduct , to ensure it has special character?

```
    this.editAddressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'CustomerName': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      'UnitNumber': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      'StreetAddress': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      'CityStateZip': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]]
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validator has pattern method [see the link](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern). You can pass any string or Regex as a parameter to it. It will check for valid input against our passed string or Regex.

```
this.editAddressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'CustomerName': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      'UnitNumber': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      'StreetAddress': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      'CityStateZip': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.pattern('.*,+.*')]]
    })
```

Comment: you can use `Validators.pattern('.*,+.*')`.